# Javascript - How to get the value back on a Click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, getelementbyid

Thanks by advance for the help.
I'm not really friendly with Javascript...

I've got a five stars review system and I'm trying to get the value of the rating (on a scale of 1 to 5) and push it in a hidden input for a form.

Any informations on "How to get the value on the 'XXXXX' space" will be appreciated.

Thanks :)

Here's the code :)

```js
var rating = {
 init: function() {
  var ratingWidth = $('.rating-select span').width();
  var step = ratingWidth / 5;

  $('.rating-select').mousemove(function(e) {
   var x = e.pageX -  $(this).offset().left;
   x = Math.ceil(x / step) * step;
   $('.rating-select span span').width(x);
   $(this).data('rating', x/step);
  });

  $('.rating-select').mouseleave(function(e) {
   var newWidth = $(this).find('select').val();
   $('.rating-select span span').width(newWidth*step);
  });

  $('.rating-select').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).find('select').val($(this).data('rating'));
   document.getElementById("hiddenForm").value = /* VALUE */;
  });
 }
};
```

```css
.rating {
 color: #ca293e;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 letter-spacing: 5px;
}
.rating.rating-select {
 cursor: pointer;
}
.rating > span {
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.rating > span:before {
 content: "\f006\f006\f006\f006\f006";
 font-family: 'fontAwesome' !important;
 margin-right: -5px;
}
.rating > span span {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 height: 100%;
 line-height: 25px;
}
.rating > span span:after {
 content: "\f005\f005\f005\f005\f005";
 position: absolute;
 top: -3px;
 left: 0;
 font-family: 'fontAwesome' !important;
 width: 100%;
 margin-right: -5px;
 overflow: hidden;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="rating rating-select">
 <span><span></span></span>
 <select>
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

Thansk for help :)

Comment: Is that 5 imaginary stars? :) can you also provide the HTML/CSS so we know that the .rating-select class has been applied to?

Comment: Give us some example markup, and an example `XXXXXXX` value.

Comment: The element that initiated the click event – usually the element the user clicked – is passed to the event handler in the event object's `targetElement` property. In your code `e.targetElement`.

Comment: The code is underneath :)

Comment: document.getElementById("hiddenForm").value = /* VALUE */; is invalid.. please check.....

Comment: You are already extracting the `score` in your code (as a 1-5 number) and setting it to the choice list using `$(this).data('rating')` which works fine. So what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out the jQuery [Raty](http://wbotelhos.com/raty) plugin, it's made for this and it's really easy to use.

With this you can get your score this way:

```
<div id="raty1"></div>

<script>
$('#raty1').raty({
   click: function(score, evt) {
     alert('ID: '+this.id+' Score: '+score);
   }
});
</script>
```

Comment: @AdrienTanaka Then please accept my answer, thank you!

Comment: sorry :) I'm not stackoverflow-friendly x)
It's done ! Thanks m8 !